# Jquery Selector for Table Data with Title

Tags: jquery, html-table, selector

I have a table with a class and a few table rows with classes (all of these are classes since multiple similar tables are generated from the same code) and I want to get some information out of the table data contained therein that has a title. It looks something like this:

```
<table class='mytable'><br/>
<tr>< td></td></tr><br/>
<tr class ='useful'><td title='hasTitle'>9</td></tr><br/>
</table><br/>
```

(added in spaces to the html because i'm not sure how to get it to display the tags..)

Is there a way in jquery to select the 9 (so the inner text of the table data) based on the table class and the table row and td title? I would assume so but I'm not sure. I'm guessing it would look something like

```
  $('#mytable tr#useful td[title='hasTitle']).html();
```

but I am not sure if that selectors syntax is correct or not.

Comment: Try `$(".mytable tr.useful td[title='hasTitle']").text();` `#`is for `id`, where as `.` is for class http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: #mytable refers to the name of an element. Your table has no name, myTable is the class. Classes have a period in front of them, so $('.myTable') would return the table. Also, in HTML you should use double quotes: for example class="mytable"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mytable tr.useful td[title="hasTitle"]').html();
```

As you're note to `class`, not `id` for table, so you should use `.` instead of `#`.

Read about jQuery **[id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)** and **[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mytable tr.useful td[title="hasTitle"]').html()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6AGwp/)**.

You're referencing ID's when you should be referencing classes. `#` selects an ID while `.` selects a class.

An alternative would be to use the code you have (with a small quote correction so it was `$('#mytable tr#useful td[title="hasTitle"]').html();`), and change the HTML of your table to:

```
<table id='mytable'><br/>
<tr><td></td></tr><br/>
<tr id='useful'><td title='hasTitle'>9</td></tr>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector jquery is like "CSS" you write :

```
$('#mytable tr#useful td[title='hasTitle']).html();
```

Here you're looking for an object with the **ID** "mytable" with a tr inside ....

You should write something like :

```
$('table.mytable tr.useful td[title="hasTitle"]').html();
```